# How to join an array into string and add it to a textarea with line breaks?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is what I am trying to do

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two','three']

const mydiv = document.createElement('textarea')
mydiv.innerText = arr.join('\r\n')
document.body.append(mydiv)
```

Searching some other answers, they say use `\r` (not sure why) but in both cases it doesn't work.

If I create a `div` instead of a `textarea` then `\n` does the trick.

Comment: `<textarea>` elements should use the `value` property, not `innerText`

Comment: @Phil Yep, that's what I realised after the fist answer. I was using div first, then changed it to a text area forgetting that it needed `value` - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `\r` and you are all set.  Also, I am setting the `value` property of the `textarea` in my response.  See the code below.

This code works for me:

```
var arr = ['one', 'two','three']

const mydiv = document.createElement('textarea')
mydiv.value = arr.join('\n');
document.body.append(mydiv);
```

Comment: `value` - thank you, in a moment of madness I was using innerText and '\n' was ignored in the textarea

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use `innerHTML` to add the line breaks you're going for.

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two','three']

const mydiv = document.createElement('textarea')
mydiv.innerHTML = arr.join('\n')
document.body.append(mydiv)
```